# Illustrator: how to export artwork by layers

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, export

I made a large project with a bunch of layers, but I need each layer exported as it's own (.jpg/.png) image.

I know there's a way to export my project by artboards, but now It's all in separate layers (on one artboard).

What would be the easiest way for me to export all my layers (~25) without cloning each layer to a new artboard (and then dealing with all the placement etc.)?

Is it even possible? Would I have to use a script?

Comment: If you have Illustrator CC, there's the built in [Asset Export](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/export-assets-web-app-design.html) and [Illustrator Layer Exporter Extension](https://github.com/davidderaedt/Illustrator-Layer-Exporter). These are both meant for screen use. The built int asset export requires you to add each asset to the panel one by one, where as the extension uses top level layers I believe. It's been a while since I last used it. I should note [the script](https://gist.github.com/TomByrne/7816376)  posted by @Ovaryraptor is just as easy to use.

Comment: Do the exports' dimensions need to match the art, or the artboard?

Comment: @NickCombsn yes, preferably.

Comment: You can export a layered PSD from Illustrator using 'export as'. But it's, in my experience, unreliable. Best bet is to check 'maximum editability'  which creates layer groups (folders) for each layer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [this nice script by Tom Byrne.](https://gist.github.com/TomByrne/7816376)

[Just copy this code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TomByrne/7816376/raw/0e1b965f41a1b4a1d63d455766cfca33c9362865/MultiExporter.jsx) into a notepad and save it as all files and with the filename `MultiExporter.jsx`.

Then drop a copy of that into your scripts folder. It can be found under

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator [YOUR VERSION]\Presets\en_[YOUR LANGUAGE]\Scripts
```

OR

```
C:\Program Filesx86\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator[YOURVERSION]\Presets\en_[YOUR LANGUAGE]\Scripts
```

Then in Illustrator, use the File > Scripts > MultiExporter option to bring up the dialogue box. From there it’s all fairly self explanatory.

[image]

Once you have each layer exported you can just split the pdf up and place each "page" as a new layer or whatever you need to do to recover your work!

Comment: I get an syntax error, I am using Mac.. Is there a separate script for Mac?

Comment: Probably not, you can check the forks on GitHub to see if anyone altered the original to work on a Mac.

Comment: Unfortunately not working in Illustrator 2021

Answer (score 6):

if you are using illustrator cc 2017 , you just need to use illustrator asset export feature.
just right click to your layer in Artboard and select collect to export option. 
follow same for all layers. 
once you've done , go to file > export > export for screens and select assets tab (if not already selected) and check and layers you want to export  and lastly click on export asset button.[image: send layer to asset export]
[image: export option]

Comment: I suggest that this be marked as the answer, its extremely easy to do and solves the issues outlined in the original question

Comment: This only lets you export specific assets though, not layers as a whole. Unless I am missing something? If I want to export an entire layer, including the empty space in the artboard (to have a square png) it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is simply turning off all but the one layer and saving it as 25 files, if saving as a PDF you can then open the files in acrobat and compile them into one document