# How to extract in batch images from one file in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, batch-processing, illustrator-scripting

I have a huge amount of seamless patterns. There is anywhere from 1-25 patterns per file.

I want to extract each pattern to a separate file.

Is there any automated or semi-automated way to do this?

I'd like to output is as .AI, as I want to make one more batch operation.

[image]

### Update:

(with requests from comments)

- Version: CC 2018.
- Every pattern is on it's own layer (and numbers are on a different layer)
- Solutions which appear in suggested question do not allow to save as AI.

Comment: What version of Illustrator?

Comment: @שelz a better question is what is the layer structure like. Is each pattern on it's own layer or are they all on one?

Comment: @Ovaryraptor a **different** question.

Comment: [This question may help you](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/103629/63979)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illustrator: how to export artwork by layers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/103629/illustrator-how-to-export-artwork-by-layers)

Comment: Ovaryraptor is right. I made a script a while back that basically does this. It looked in a "photo" layer and exported each item in it while batching files in a directory. But if the patterns are in the same layer as everything else, we'd have to rely on selection or some other way to single them out (like testing the dimensions).

Comment: Version: CC 2018.

Every pattern has own layer (and number are different layer)

Comment: @שelz Unfortunately posted solution seems like it doesn't match what I [want to do next](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/104130/how-to-multipy-images-in-batch-in-illustrator). Please take a look. I'm very grateful for your time guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the (new) Asset Export, you can export them as **.SVG**

You will just have to drag them into there and then go through with the export.

It isn't **.AI** however, they are *vector* and you can open up **.SVG** in Illustrator and still apply actions (batch) to them.

---

Read more about the [Asset Export panel at Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/collect-assets-export-for-screens.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this nice script by Tom Byrne.](https://gist.github.com/TomByrne/7816376)

[Just copy this code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TomByrne/7816376/raw/0e1b965f41a1b4a1d63d455766cfca33c9362865/MultiExporter.jsx) into a notepad and save it as all files and with the filename `MultiExporter.jsx`.

Then drop a copy of that into your scripts folder. It can be found under

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator [YOUR VERSION]\Presets\en_[YOUR LANGUAGE]\Scripts
```

OR

```
C:\Program Filesx86\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator[YOURVERSION]\Presets\en_[YOUR LANGUAGE]\Scripts
```

Then in Illustrator, use the File > Scripts > MultiExporter option to bring up the dialogue box. From there it’s all fairly self explanatory.

[image]

Once you have each layer exported you can just split the pdf up and place each "page" as a new layer or whatever you need to do to recover your work!