# How to multipy images in batch in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, batch-processing, illustrator-scripting

*This is a continuation of [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/104126/how-to-extract-in-batch-images-from-one-file-in-illustrator).*

I will have a huge amount of seamless pattern in vector format.

I want to multiply them by 9, so each pattern would occur three times in three rows.

Then I'd like to leave them as AI with 5000x5000 px workspace size, or eventually export to PNG.

[image]

Comment: An *action* that clones, rotates and positions them is probably your best option. (or a Script)

Comment: @שelz can you elaborate a little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the tiles *are* seamless patterns which do *not* require any rotating and merely need to be duplicated and aligned..... I would actually use `Place` and `Effects` with linked files.... A couple minutes of set up to make any future pattern change take only a few seconds.

---

So you have 1 file, and you know the size is 100x100px....

[image]

Open a new AI file and choose `File > Place` and select your file. This **links** to the single file.

[image]

Select the Linked image and choose `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform`.

Enter a value in the **Move - Horizontal** area which correlates to the width of your tile, in my case I used 100pts/px. And enter 2 in the **Copies** field since you want 2 copies to appear....

[image]

Click `OKAY` and you'll see the effect in the **Appearance Panel** (Window > Appearance).

[image]

Click-drag that `Transform` Effect to the "New" icon at the bottom of the Appearance Panel to duplicate it:

[image]

Now click one the `Transform` effects in the panel, either one, it doesn't matter which.

The Transform Effect Options window will appear again. This time enter the **Vertical** distance in the Move area, and set the Horizontal back to zero. Copies should still be set at 2, leave that as it is.

[image]

And Click `OKAY`.

You now have a 3x3 grid based on a single placed link. Save this as a "Master" working file if you'd like.

To change patterns, use the **Links Panel** (Window > Links) to merely relink the image, and all the subsequent duplicates will update as well....

[image]

Then simply save as whatever you need.

---

<sub>**Note I really don't know the native tiles size for these patterns so numbers are rounded for general clarity. Tiles won't line up correctly due to this.**</sub>

---

## Update after comments.....

---

It appears you are using svg files that are *not* actually patterns, but rather just expanded artwork. Illustrator **embeds** these files rather than linking to them. **The above still works. However...** You'll need to plan differently for changing the initial tile.

- Place the tile
- Follow the `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` settings
- When you get the end and you have the 3x3 grid of tiles, Select the initial tile and drag it to the **Graphic Styles Panel** (Window > Graphic Styles)

For the next pattern....

- Select All
- Delete
- Place next pattern
- Click the graphic style you created (It should automatically create the 3x3 grid.)

[image]

(I'm using `Place` with expanded art svg files in the above animation.)

You could choose to resave the svg assets as .ai files, or make the svg files *actual* pattern-filled rectangles rather than expanded art, then the link method will work.

Comment: Thank you, however, I couldn't not get links working. https://i.imgur.com/IapoN8r.gifv

Comment: Ahh it appears your SVG file is not actually a pattern but expanded artwork. @J.Baptiste --This leaves 2 options.... resave those asset files as .ai files and then it will work. It's the svg format which is actually *embedding* the artwork rather than linking to it. Or.... if you must keep those in svg format.. they need to be actual patterns, not expanded tiles.

Comment: See answer update @J.Baptiste

Answer (score 1):

Second answer as this is a different approach which *may* work in your scenario (depending on how your pattern was made).

Much simpler (if it does in fact work)

---

You can just select the pattern and *drag* it into your swatches panel, your pattern is now a swatch

You can now make a huge square (3x the size) and apply it with that pattern as a fill (from the swatches).

Example:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused by your comment. I'm not really sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an action which does the following:

Note: for the action to work, all of the squares **have** to be the same size (in my case I set them at 450 - adjust accordingly*)

Starting with my initial pattern on the artboard

Part 1: (the first 3 squares)

1. Select all
2. Copy (<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
3. Paste in front (<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
4. Move (the copy) 450 (x)
5. Rotate -90°
6. Paste in front (again - it will paste in spot of original square) and then move that copy -450 (x) and rotate it as well -90°

Now I need the action to select everything again, so:

Part 2: (the rest)

Again

1. Select all (this time it's all 3 squares)
2. Reflect (as a copy) *vertically*
3. Move -450 (y)

Now just take you final line,

4. Copy
5. Paste in front
6. Move 900 (y)

<sub>*450 is size of square, so any movement that is 450 should be adjusted for size of square, 900 is 2x square)</sub>

---

Creating the action slowly (you can sorta see what's happening):

[image]

[image]

---

At the end, this is the action.... in action:

[image]

---

<sub>If you've made it this far, [link to action](https://nofile.io/f/FwYGJ7ppHU6/Pattern+Action.aia)</sub>