# Sketch export entire canvas size for every object in an artboard?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, sketch-app, adobe-after-effects

Is it possible to create one separate, full-canvas-size .png for each of 100 or so vector shapes within a Sketch artboard?

I have an artboard that has about 100 vector shapes, and I'm hoping to animate the visibility of each of those shapes within After Effects. But I don't want to export all of the pieces from Sketch *and then* have to place them all in the right place manually once I get into AE. I would like to export each of the 100 shapes including the full canvas size (1280x810), *not trimmed down to the size of the shape*, and then just dump those all in AE and animate them appearing.

Is possible in Sketch? What about Illustrator?

Comment: There is solution for illustrator https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/103629/illustrator-how-to-export-artwork-by-layers

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution, but here are the steps I ended up taking (still interested in a better option if anyone knows one):

1. Create 100 rectangles that are the full size of the canvas with a 1px border
2. Select a single rectangle and single vector shape one-by-one
3. Group
4. Repeat 99 times
5. Select all the groups, make exportable, export

That gave me what I need for After Effects. It's doing the trick, but not the most elegant solution (I *think* I need the 1px border stroke on the rectangle in order to preserve the canvas size; I don't want any .05% opacity settings to make my image cloudy).

Answer (score 0):

One way of going down it would be the [Sketch2AE](https://google.github.io/sketch2ae/) plugin that is currently half-broken/half-working.

Might even be worth [downloading an older version Sketch](https://sketchapp.com/updates/), and going from there. Just trying to help you avoid creating 100 rectangles